# Laravel 7 - Spatie Permissions: Assign User with different role per team

Tags: laravel-7

Well I am trying to do the following:

1. A user can have a specific role (user, elevated user, admin)
2. Most people will be registered as users, but some will be granted the elevated user role
3. Elevated users will be able to make their own teams
4. In each team, elevated users will be able to invite ANY user registered to my Laravel application
5. If a user is invited to a team, he will be given a specific task to do (aka a team role)

I made the following roles:

```
    $role = Role::create(['name' => 'Elevated User']);
    $role = Role::create(['name' => 'User']);
    $role = Role::create(['name' => 'Admin']);
```

How can I achieve such a thing?

Is it possible to do that by using Spatie?

- I thought of assigning my user with a specific role for the whole
  application, but grand a specific role just for each team he belongs
  to.
- A user may belong to different teams and have different roles in each team

Example:

User Chris has the User role

- Chris belongs to team A and his role on the team is "editor"
- Chris also belongs to team B and his role on that team is "leader"

Each role that Chris has in those two different teams, grand him different permissions for team A or B

Answer (score 0):

- Requires a user and teams connection.
- Role and permission must be linked to it.
- You can do the required condition there.

For example, like this

```
Models/User.php

public function hasAuthorized($team_id, $role) {    
   return $this->userTeams()->where('team_id', $team_id)->first()->hasRole($role); 
}
```